# Alignment in Siunitx with Comma separators

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

How can I right align the following two columns, just specifying that there will be at most 5 integer digits and never any decimals? I can't seem to get the right combination of options. I can align it properly, but I lose all the commas for some reason.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r
S[table-format = 5.0,group-digits=true,group-separator={,},table-number-alignment = right,input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-digits=true,group-separator={\,}]
S[table-format = 5.0,group-separator={,},table-number-alignment = right,input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-digits=true,group-separator={\,}]
}
siunitx: &\num{19000}                &\num{19,000} \\
siunitx: &\num{7,000}                &\num{7,000} \\
siunitx: &\num{900}                &\num{900} \\
siunitx: &\num{90}                &\num{90} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `\num`  *inside* an `S` column: that's not how it works. The column contents are parsed 'directly':

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-decimal-markers = .,input-ignore = {,},table-number-alignment = right,
  group-separator={,}, group-four-digits = true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  rS[table-format = 5.0]S[table-format = 5.0]
}
siunitx: &19000                &19,000 \\
siunitx: &7,000                &7,000 \\
siunitx: &900                  &900 \\
siunitx: &90                   &90 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignment is fine, but the commas are still missing. I need them in the output. How can I put them back after using `input-ignore={,}`? If I add a `group-separator = {,}` it doesn't put a comma after the 7 in 7000, only after the 19 in 19000!

Comment: @user2146441 They have _nothing_ to do with those in the input: I've added the appropriate options